# PySpark UDF On Nested Array

Tags: pyspark

I am new to PySpark and I am attempting to create a UDF that will perform an operation on a string. The column I am attempting to use the UDF on has a type of: array<structday:string,month:string,year:string> where some of the years are numbers and others written.

A typical row within this "day_dict" column looks like:

```
[{20, 5, 1997}]
```

For the time being I just want to print the output before I perform any operations within the UDF.

```
def isnum(col):
    print(col[0]['year'])
```

My UDF call:

```
isnumfunc = udf(isnum, ArrayType(StructType(StringType())))
    isnumfunc.select(isnumfunc(col("day_dict"))).show()
```

But, I get a:

```
TypeError: 'StringType' object is not iterable
```

What do I need to change to print the year?

Answer (score 0):

Please acquint yourself with schemas before you proceed. They are the backbone of dataframes API. StructType is a special schema type that is used to nest a collection of items individually, in an array or map. There are special methods of handling it and you do not need a udf.

Schema

```
sch = "id integer,col array<struct<structday:string,month:string,year:string>>"


 or

myschema = StructType(
[
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("col",
                ArrayType(
                    StructType([
                        StructField("structday", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("month", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("year", StringType(), True)
                    ])
    ))
]
)
```

Data Frame

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,[('20', '5', '1997')])],myschema)

df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,[('20', '5', '1997')])],sch)
```

Select First Column in Array Struct

```
s = df.selectExpr('inline(col)')
s.select(s.columns[0]).show()

+---------+
|structday|
+---------+
|       20|
+---------+
```